# find sum of all elements in array in swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

I have array like this

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I tried   `var totalSum = arr.map({$0.points}).reduce(0, +)`
but not worked

can I find all objects sum value?

Comment: why `$0.points` ?? why not only `$0`?

Comment: This cannot work. An `Int` doesn’t have a `points` member.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to drop the `map` & `points`

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

let totalSum = arr.reduce(0, +)

print("totalSum \(totalSum)")
```

Comment: Here your array is on interger but my array is in string. I am trying to do reduce but it not working can you please help on this. Thanks

Comment: You can't add strings, you have to convert to type Int, Double or Float etc.

Answer (score 3):

> This is the easiest/shortest method to sum of array.

**Swift 3,4:**

```
let arrData = [1,2,3,4,5]
sum = arrData.reduce(0, +)
```

**Or**

```
let arraySum = arrData.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
```

**Swift 2:**

sum = arrData.reduce(0, combine: +)

Answer (score 0):

Without using any built in function.

```
let arr = Array(1...100)
var sum = 0

arr.forEach { (num) in
    sum = sum + num
}
```